# Delete entire row if all cells are empty in range of cells using Xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I have many ways but i'm struggling to improve the performance of this code. Any alternative please do suggest.
I am trying to build a code to delete the entire row if all cell are empty in a range, i so far have tried the below code which works fine but the performance is super slow

```
import xlwings as xw
wb=xw.Book("example.xlsb")
del_rng = wb.sheets[1].range("A8:DW91242")
for i in range(del_rng.shape[0],0,-1):
    row=del_rng.rows[i-1]
    if all(cell.value is None for cell in row):
        row.delete()
```

Comment: I suggest to use pandas if possible, it might be faster. At first, load the data into a dataframe with `import pandas as pd` and `df = pd.read_excel("example.xlsb")`, then drop the empty rows with [`df = df.dropna(how='all')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), and then export the data to an excel file with `df.to_excel("example_results.xlsx")`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this help others, I spend 2 days behind this.

I created 2 LastRow Range variable:
Var 1 for Column A which holds the last row of blanks
Var 2 for Column B which hold the start row of blanks or end of non empty rows
then i deleted the range

now it deletes in super quickly

I used the below code:

```
lastRow_A = wb.sheets[1].range(7,1).end('down').row
lastRow_A=lastRow_A-1
lastRow_B = wb.sheets[1].range(7,2).end('down').row
lastRow_B=lastRow_B+1
wb.sheets[1].range(f"A{lastRow_A}:B{lastRow_B}").api.EntireRow.Delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `del_rng` to be a very large range, from A8 to DW91242 - that's well over 11 million cells. You can use `Sheet.used_range` to autofit `del_rng` to only the data that's used, which would significantly decrease the amount of cells your code needs to take into account:

```py
import xlwings as xw
wb=xw.Book("example.xlsb")
del_rng = wb.sheets[1].used_range
for i in range(del_rng.shape[0],0,-1):
    row=del_rng.rows[i-1]
    if all(cell.value is None for cell in row):
        row.delete()
```

Comment: No, performance is still slow. can i make it for column B, if cell in column B value is blank, delete the entire row

Comment: It depends on if that would work for your use case. If that's valid, you can try that and see if it's still slow.

Comment: No, it does not help. Still on the slower side. This is just one automation of many of my project. If user have to delete rows manually then i cant efficiency in my project Is there any other way we can make this execution faster, please suggest